# Google app engine openID login redirect with query string

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using OpenID federated login in my app engine application. I have encountered the following problem when using redirects after login.

Login URLs generated using `userService.createLoginURL()` remove query strings when redirecting to the callback URL.

As an example, clicking the login link from the URL `/handler?QueryString` will redirect to `/handler` after logging in, and the `QueryString` parameter will not be provided.

I think this is the same problem described in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/ugzZ_-vo_PE).

I would like to know the cause behind this issue and also possible workarounds.